# How to make FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED work along with TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG

Tags: android

I have been developing an Android App with a Lock Screen Feature, such that once my LockScreen Activity is started the default Lock Screen should be temporarily disabled until the activity exists.

On searching I found it easy to do so by using FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. But when I added TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG so as to disable the HOME button, it stopped working.

Again searching I ended up with a solution to use the code

```
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock k1;
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
k1 = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
k1.disableKeyguard();
```

But The type KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock is deprecated.

Is there any way to make this work without using KeyguardLock?

my code-

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that my question is not relevant anymore. It is not possible to create a lockscreen for Jellybean+ phones. So dropped the feature for now.

Reasons,

1. KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock is deprecated.
2. Using onAttachedToWindow() results in error for Jellybean+.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need answer try `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` it's alternative for `KeyguardLock` and if it won't work you simply need to keep your `KeyguardLock` and add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` before `@Override`.
And also you don't always need to use `onAttachedToWindow()` you can use `this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.*here flag that you need*)` and you HAVE TO do this before `setContentView()`.